# How to using gitolite with http mode

Tags: git, http, gitolite

I am using centOS to set my own Git Server by gitolite,I want to use both ssh and http mode.
After followed the '[`smart-http.root-setup`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/f480dbf9275b7a82ccbff208f2925a25864432b9/t/smart-http.root-setup)'.

I come across a problem when I execute the git command "`git clone http://admin:admin@180.163.69.211/git/testing`".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJBVN.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double-check your `httpd.conf` defined by [`smart-http.root-setup#L81-L92`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/f480dbf9275b7a82ccbff208f2925a25864432b9/t/smart-http.root-setup#L81-L92):

```
export GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME=$PWD/gitolite-home
...
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT $GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME/repositories
ScriptAlias /git/ $GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME/gitolite-source/src/gitolite-shell/
```

Make sure `$GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME/repositories/testing.git` does exists on your server.

The [OP S.Yuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5776571/s-yuan) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850650/how-to-using-gitolite-with-http-mode/34850892#comment57563544_34850892):

> I check the `suexec.log` in `/etc/httpd/logs` and the main issue is the file exec auth error.
>   So I delete the `gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh` file. And create it again, then change the file auth.

Comment: In $GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME/repositories/ There are two dirs  "gitolite-admin.git" and "testing.git"

Comment: @S.Yuan That looks ok, then. Check the apache http logs, and `.gitolite/logs`

Comment: **2016-01-18.17:26:25     124023          'keydir' not found in '/home/git/.gitolite'; exiting**

Comment: the message in the log says the keydir not found. Is that matter?

Comment: @S.Yuan It does matter indeed: the authentication of the user depends on it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally I Fixed it._It have cost my so much time to set it. it is indeed complex for me. I asked many people for help and many article._Later,I'll record my operation step by step .and write a article in my blog

Comment: @S.Yuan Great! What was the main issue?

Comment: I check the suexec.log in /etc/httpd/logs and the main issue is the file exec auth error. so I delete the **gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh** file. and create it again,then change the file auth.

Comment: But I come accross a new issue, I want to add new repo,so I edit the gitolite.conf and push it to git server.But It does't work.

Comment: @S.Yuan OK. I have asked about it in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34897418/6309