# gitolite-admin.conf doesn't work

Tags: gitolite

I was set git server with gitolite and I have finished it Now. But One question truble me. I am set gitolite with both `ssh` and `http` mode.

I use the `gitolite-admin.conf` to control the repo and user's auth. I followed the instruction: modify the conf, git add it, git commit it and git push it. But It does't work.

**In Client** I can't clone the new repo I have add in the conf

[image]

this is my conf

[image]

the default repo 'testing' is working regularly

Comment: Is that gitolite.conf pushed to the git server in the gitolite-admin repo?

Comment: I Have execute **git push origin** command, But It did not work

Comment: the new repo can't be cloned by client

Comment: What error message do you have? Did you cloned gitolite-admin in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

That is because gitolite honors `gitolite.conf` very strictly. You need to specify these lines in the conf file

```
repo @all
     RW+    =    @all
```

This will allow you to do operations on all the repos. But, you need to understand that when you specify `@all` in `repo` section, that means every repo falls in this rule. So, even if you have something like this in the file:

```
repo foo
     R      =     xyz
```

gitolite ignores it because it sees that the repo `foo` belongs to `@all`. So, in order for clone operation to work, you need to specify `READ` permission to all the repos, something like this:

```
repo @all
     R      =    @all
```

And then you need to add all the permissions to the other repos as well, otherwise you will only be allowed to read the other repos and not write them.